Light bulb is intermittently not working
I have a room with two non-dimmable light fixtures that are connected.
The first fixture will intermittently work. When I take the bulb out of the first fixture, the second fixture won't work.
Sometimes the first fixture will flicker when turned on, then work fine. Sometimes, it won't turn on. I can immediately turn the switch off, and back on, and it usually works.
The second fixture will not work if the first doesn't work

Does the first fixture work if the bulb is out of the second fixture?

Are these lamps kinda dim? compared to what you would expect for their wattage?   I wonder if someone has put them in series not parallel.

I think both lights are wired incorrectly. I'm going to change it to a single light. Is it best to run the incoming power into the light, then to the switch, or to the switch then to the light?

Could you answer my question? It would help to confirm how they are likely miswired. You could also switch off the circuit breaker, and remove the switch and lights from the wall or ceiling without disconnecting any wires, and add clear pictures of them showing the wire connections for more help.

The first fixture doesn't work when the second light is removed. The first one just flickers, and won't turn on now

Sounds like a loose connection. There's some considerable risk that could start a fire as the loose connection arcs and sparks between being connected and not being connected (recall that US Electrical code is published by the NFPA - National Fire Prevention Association - since that's the more normal route to killing folks with electricity.) There's a (relatively small) chance that it's actually a bad switch - possible, but less common than a loose connection. If there are spring-loaded back stab connections, (wire is not clamped by a screw) those are often a problem.
Given that the second fixture does not work if the first does not, or has the bulb removed, and the first does not if the bulb is removed from the second, it's highly likely that the two are wired in series so each gets half-voltage, rather than in parallel so each gets full voltage as is normal. Which means that someone who didn't know what they were doing has been at the wiring in the past. You'll need to be wary of other things they may have done wrong.
Whether that's a "call in an electrician" or "fix it yourself" problem depends in part on the type of dwelling (apartments and other "multiple dwelling unit" occupancies often are required to have an electrician do electrical work, due to the hazard to others.) Some local jurisdictions also require that. In most places in the US, if you own your own single-family house you can choose to work on the wiring your self, with varying levels of official oversight depending on the jurisdiction and scope of work.
The other part it depends on is you, whether you think it's in your DIY skills, or your willingness to learn enough to put it there and do the work in a manner that's safe for you and safe for anyone else inhabiting the house, long term. You'll need to identify the correct circuit to turn off, verify that power is off, and then check and correct the connections of wires that are affecting the lights.

Thanks. I think both lights are wired incorrectly. Its a small room, I'll probably switch the lighting to a single light. Hopefully, that's the easiest solution for now. Is it best to run the incoming power into the light, then go to the switch, or the switch first then the light?

In an already built house, unless you like ripping the place up for no reason, it's generally best to see how it was done, and stick with that, other than correcting errors. Used to be more common to bring power to the light, then switch loop to the switch. Post 2011 code changes it becomes more of a wash, since bringing power to the switch directly means you may not need any /3 cable, while doing a post-2011 to code switch loop requires /3 cable. It's highly unlikely that you need to replace the cables at all - just fix the connections, most likely.

If the place was built/wired before 2011 code took effect, you can simply repair the (likely) switch loop to function correctly - you don't have to bring it up to current code (unless you want a smart switch or occupancy sensor that needs neutral. Those are why code changed on that point.)

Ok, thanks for the help
